# Embedded JavaScript code is not responding

Tags: javascript, html

I have dropdown text box form and open clicking on the dropdown button **nothing happens**. Below is my code, I am working on an Angular 4 framework:

```js
$('#demo-combo-box-2').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.currentTarget).parents('.input-group').siblings('.combo-box-scroll').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="combo-box">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Combobox">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" type="button" id="demo-combo-box-2">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                  </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="combo-box-scroll hidden">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a class="list-group-item">Item 1</a>
          <a class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
          <a class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
          <a class="list-group-item">Item 4</a>
          <a class="list-group-item">Item 5</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the snippet I made for you. It works just fine once you add the relevant jQuery and CSS

Comment: Where do you place your JavaScript code?

Comment: Place it in the head wrapped in $(function(){ ... });

Comment: You mean I create a head tag in component.html and I copy paste the JS code into it?

Comment: Yes, in <script>...</script> tags

Comment: So I enclosed it in script tag within my html yet the button is unresponsive

Comment: You need CSS AND  jQuery too `<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>$(functionI() {$('#demo-combo-box-2').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.currentTarget).parents('.input-group').siblings('.combo-box-scroll').toggleClass('hidden');
}); });</script><style>.hidden { display:none }</style></head>`

Comment: For Angular 4 look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897383/how-hide-and-show-in-angular-4-0